# Is it possible to tail Ansible AWX logs via curl?

Tags: shell, curl, ansible-awx

I would like to create a curl output live in a single shell command, to log a output from an Ansible job in realtime filling a log file.

I've tried this command:

```
curl -f -k -N -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST \
    --user admin:awxsecret \
    http://192.168.42.100/api/v2/jobs/1620/
```

...but it only returns the output generated thus far, not waiting for newly-generated content.

Comment: Since you're using `-N`/`--no-buffer`, curl *is* emitting your output as quickly as it gets it. If you want to prove this to yourself, use `strace`, `sysdig` or a similar tool to compare the timing of the `recv()` calls to those of the following `write()`s. If you want help with any remaining issue, we'll need a [mcve] -- code we can run ourselves to see that there really *is* a problem.

Comment: ...are you sure the REST API itself is written for long-polling clients? If it isn't, what you have is a server-side problem and we can't help you.

Comment: ("as it intends" doesn't really tell us much about what's wrong, either; what's *actually* happening? Is the stream ending when it reaches the last of the output from the server so far? That's *definitely* an issue with the server's/API's behavior, not an issue with curl's behavior, if so).

Comment: ok, when I said as intended, I mean a like tail -f command, the curl would be listening the json log for as long as it last.

Comment: curl **does** keep a socket open until the server closes it. Always, 100% of the time, unless there's an error or the user cancels it (or there's an explicitly configured timeout or such, but again, that requires explicit configuration). If it's closing the socket, it's the server doing so, so you need to look at the API docs &c. for the server.

Comment: So I'm afraid that I need to do like this: while true; do curl -f -k -N -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST \
    --user admin:awxsecret \
    http://192.168.42.100/api/v2/jobs/1620/; sleep 3; done

Comment: We couldn't possibly tell you if that's what you need to do because you aren't telling us what API it is so we can look at its docs to see if there's a long-polling or SSE option or a WebSockets API.

Comment: Does the vendor provide a browser-based client that can tail the logs? A good place to start (other than reviewing the API docs) is to use your browser's debugger to look at what the API calls used by the official client are when accomplishing the same purpose.

Comment: I've made an educated guess as to your API, and updated the question to be asking about it *specifically*.

Comment: ...that said, it looks to be like AWX *does* support websockets, so if you want a streaming view, that's almost certainly what you'll need to use. (Indeed, per https://jpmens.net/2017/10/20/a-few-notes-on-ansible-awx/, the websocket API *is* how the official web-based client streams its updates).

Answer (score 0):

As @charles-duffy said: "AWX does support websockets" I will work with this solution.